# Is Python multiprocessing suitable for comparing two very large gzipped files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, large-data

I am sorry for posting a lot of background in order to illustrate my problem, but here goes: I have created a script in python 2.7 to compare two large files and output any differences. The script currently takes around nineteen hours to complete and I would like to potentially reduce this via multi-core processing.

The files are structured like this:

```
r1 count:3 contained:True   -   rs692242298 40  ACGCTTTCCGGCCG  IIIIIIIIIIIIII  2   
r1 count:3 contained:True   -   rs344292768 73  ACGCTTTCCGGCCG  IIIIIIIIIIIIII  2   
r1 count:3 contained:True   -   rs326313795 23  ACGCTTTCCGGCCG  IIIIIIIIIIIIII  2   
r10 count:592 contained:True    +   rs690696575 4   CGGCCGGAAAGCGC  IIIIIIIIIIIIII  3   
r10 count:592 contained:True    +   rs333942854 30  CGGCCGGAAAGCGC  IIIIIIIIIIIIII  3   
r10 count:592 contained:True    +   rs323000429 65  CGGCCGGAAAGCGC  IIIIIIIIIIIIII  3   
r10 count:592 contained:True    +   rs341309868 76  CGGCCGGAAAGCGC  IIIIIIIIIIIIII  3   
r11 count:1 contained:False +   rs346130515 43  CTCCGTCCGGCG    IIIIIIIIIIII    10  
r11 count:1 contained:False +   rs336124149 75  CTCCGTCCGGCG    IIIIIIIIIIII    10
```

... and when I say they are large, I mean VERY large. Each file (gzipped) takes up around 30 GB and if unzipped 3 TB (so I never unzip!!). For anyone interested, this is output from a genomic alignment program called bowtie. The comparisons are line to line. Most lines will have an exact match in the other file, but I need to find and output lines that are unique (no match in the other file - both ways).

The files are structured such that all lines with the same id (the leftmost r#) are grouped together. The id numbers (r1, r10, r11 in the example) are kind of growing, but due to multicore processing in bowtie the pattern is not steady (hence the gap between r1 and r10). This also means that the relative position of a block of lines for a particular id differs between the files. The number of lines for a particular id is frequently several millions.

I use a generator to iteratively return a list of all the lines for an id. As soon as I have two similar ids (one for each file), I compare the lists for that id by adding the lists to a frozenset and then I get the unique lines by using the difference method:

```
lines_file1 = frozenset(file_1_lines)
lines_file2 = frozenset(file_2_lines)
unique_lines = list(lines_file1.difference(lines_file2)) + list(lines_file2.difference(lines_file1))
```

I then write the unique lines to output and delete the original lists to save memory.

When timing the events, most of the time is spend on "reading" the files (app. 10 hours). As this is primarily CPU-bound (due to the compression) I think I could potentially cut this in half by dividing it into two processes. If I could then parallelize the other tasks, I could potentially cut the overall time from 19 to 5 hours.
Use of the word "potentially" here reflects that I may not fully understand the strengths and weaknesses of Python multiprocessing and if what I hope to achieve is even feasible.

From the attempts that I have done so far, one of the biggest barriers (if I have understood this correctly) is that everything needs to be pickled, which simply is not viable with such large amounts of data. If this is correct I would say that the usability of Python multiprocessing for analysis of genetic data is next to nothing.

So, to formulate a concrete question: Would it be possible (perhaps through some kind of mapping to avoid pickling everything) to create a producer process(es) that reads both input files in parallel and outputs 2-tuples where each tuple contains two lists of lines for one id?

Could I then make a consumer that would access the list/queue of such tuples to compare each pair and output unique lines to the SAME output file?

If the answer to the above is yes/maybe, I would be grateful if you could point me in the right direction. I have to admit that right now my take on the multiprocessing "powers" of Python is that it is useless for something like this and that my time is better spend elsewhere. But I kind of wish this is merely due to my own ignorance. Thank you.

Comment: Are the files stored on SSDs or rotating disks? If rotating disks, you should definitely look into optimizing the decompression. Even some of the most advanced compression algorithms on mid-range CPUs can be decompressed as faster than disk speeds.

Comment: They are stored on rotating disks and since the compression is so huge, I completely agree that optimization could provide a significant improvement. In fact, the compression is so big that I believe the bottleneck is the CPU, so even if it were SSDs, I think the performance gain would still be significant. I just don't know how to deal with the large amounts of data in relation to multiprocessing. The pickling looks like a game stopper - but that is just my perspective.